# Installing a python module on windows

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to install a module called Swish-E 0.5 and for some reason im getting an error when running the command

```
python setup.py install
```

I keep getting this error no matter what module i try to install. I have tried installing other modules to see if the problem lay in that specific module however it does not.

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W
3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -IC:\Python26\include -IC:\P
ython26\PC /TcSwishE.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.6\Release\SwishE.obj
SwishE.c
SwishE.c(35) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'swish-e.h': No such
 file or directory
error: command '"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe"' fa
iled with exit status 2
```

This is the error DOS keeps dumping, no matter what module.  Unfortunately i cannot find the binary file for the module i need therefore i must fix this problem.

I have a feeling it is something to do with my C compiler if someone could please help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I you haven't already, install [Swish-e](http://swish-e.org/download/index.html). If you have, then grab the development files from the source tarball and put them somewhere the compiler can find them.

Comment: @Aaron: No, he is installing the *Python bindings* for it.

Comment: i have installed swish-e although i dont think there any development files that come with the binary installer version

Answer (score 0):

Search your hard disk for the file `swish-e.h` and make sure the directory is mentioned in the command line after a `-I` (= add include path).

Comment: i found the swish-e.h file and placed it in the same directory as my setup file but still it doesn't work

Comment: Is the directory of the setup file mentioned anywhere in the error message? if not, then this won't help. Try to put the file into `C:\Python26\include`

Comment: thanks that helped but now im getting 

LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'swish-e.lib'

Comment: Same problem, same solution: Locate the file `swish-e.lib` and copy it into some directory which you see in the error message (probably `C:\Python26\Libs`)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install/compile Swish-e itself before building Python module for it. Also missing header points to this cause - the Python module uses Swish-e library and headers.

Comment: i installed swish-e from swish-e.org, i used the latest version of the windows installer...could it be that i need to set some environment variables

Comment: You need to add the folder to include and library search paths.